# Laravel Import SQLite

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, pdo

I am trying to import an SQLite file in my Laravel project which I am importing and storing at runtime. When I try, I find that sometimes it works and other times it does not. Here is the code that I am using to generate the PDO connection:

```
try{
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:'.$dbSavedLocation);
    return $db;
}
catch(\PDOException $e){
    LogRepo::logError(0, $e->getMessage(), 1, $e->getFile(), $e->getLine());
    return null;
}
```

"SMS Database process error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file" when trying to open the file?
Why would this not work? What would cause the error of

Comment: Am I mean to use some other params when opening the file?

Answer (score 0):

Is the .sqlite file opened by any other programs?

I've had it happen a few times where I've had it open in SQLiteBrowser and gotten a similar error, but having it open elsewhere will prevent Laravel from being able to open the database.

Comment: No, I dont think so. The script downloads the file from s3 and then tries to read it.

Comment: Am I mean to use some other params when opening the file?